# Excel VBA - Validation List not Saving

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I created a data validation list using the results from a sql query and it seems to work fine, but when I reopen the file, I get an error message stating there is an error with the file and the fix removes the data validation lists. Any idea how to fix this?

```
sqlQry1 = "Select distinct [Column A] from [DB].dbo.[Table]"
  recset1.Open sqlQry1, Conn
    recset1.MoveFirst
    arr = recset1.GetRows
    arr0 = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0), ",")
    Worksheets("SQL_PowerQuery_Import").Range("C3").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:=arr0
    recset1.Close
```

[image: Excel Error]

Comment: How long is `arr0` when you add the list?  There's a limit of 256 characters when you add it as a string.

Comment: I believe it is longer than 256 characters. It loads properly into the list, but breaks after saving and reopening the file.

Comment: In that case maybe consider creating a named range on a hidden sheet and put the list there.